# QueryBuilder and the MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony, query-builder

I'm programming on Symfony2 and I have a doubt: If I want to respect the MVC pattern, I should do the queries with the QueryBuilder on the Controller's actions or in methods inside the entities?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do query in Repository classes: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

> In the previous sections, you began constructing and using more complex queries from inside a controller. **In order to isolate, test and reuse these queries, it's a good idea to create a custom repository class** for your entity and add methods with your query logic there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please note that Symfony2 doesn't fully respect the MVC pattern. It provides controllers and templates (views), but not models.

A controller is a layer between 'http land' and 'application land' <sup>[[1]](http://www.slideshare.net/kriswallsmith/how-kris-writes-symfony-apps)</sup>. It's not just a layer, it should be the thinnest layer possible. On the other hand, the 2 'lands' should be big.

That means that there should be now querybuilder in the controller, but this should be done in the repository of the user. In the controller, you should just need to call one method of that repository.

More about custom repositories in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)